# Nexus generates wrong checksum of pom

Tags: maven, nexus

I use Nexus 2.14.0-01 and have the following problem:

The checksums that are computed by Nexus are different from the checksum that one gets on the command line (for the pom file). Deleting checksum files and recreating them by "Rebuild metadata" creates the same checksum files as before (with the apparently wrong checksum). Even manipulating the pom and then creating the checksum files always recreates the same wrong number.

Does Nexus have a cache for that that I need to empty? How can I convince Nexus to create correct checksum files?

Comment: Have you tried on the hard drive on the Nexus server itself and checked via md5sum/shasum ? and compare the results?

Comment: I computed the checksum on the Nexus Server itself on the command line and it was different from the one that Nexus computes (but the same as if I download the file and compute it on my computer).

Comment: Please check the release notes of the releases after your own and see if there is an existing problem of that...